# How do I clear a JTree model?(Removing all nodes)

Tags: java, model, jtree

So this is a method of mine that is called everytime a new node is added.I need the model cleared everytime.The DefaultListModel has a .clear() method.The DefaultTreeModel does not.Help?

```
    public void fillUserList(){

    List<User> userFriends = ClientController.getInstance().getPrieteniiUserului(user);

    for(int i=0;i<userFriends.size();i++){
        User user = userFriends.get(i);

        model.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(user.getNume()), root, i);

    }

    System.out.println(userFriends);

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the root node, and use the `removeAllChildren()` method?

Comment: It works.But I also needed the model.reload() called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked it out.The new code looks like this.

```
public void fillUserList(){    
    List<User> userFriends = ClientController.getInstance().getPrieteniiUserului(user);
    root.removeAllChildren(); //this removes all nodes
    model.reload(); //this notifies the listeners and changes the GUI
    for(int i=0;i<userFriends.size();i++){
        User user = userFriends.get(i);
        model.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(user.getNume()), root, i);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you actually need to *delete* ALL nodes *including root* node you should make model null. Like this:

```
mytree.setModel(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void clearTree(JTree tree) {
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
        root.removeAllChildren();
        model.reload();
    }
```